# Data not processing

Tags: php

The $var (single dollar) is a normal variable with the name var that stores any value like string, integer, float, etc. The $$var (double dollar) is a reference variable that stores the value of the $variable inside it.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: `$y = “man”;` - okay, so you need to start by reading up on some of the most elementary basics: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems you are asking the result of $y and $$y; 
$y will result into "man" and $$y will result into 100.

Notes :  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Sometimes it is convenient to be able to have variable variable names. That is, a variable name which can be set and used dynamically. A normal variable is set with a statement such as:

```
<?php $a = 'hello'; ?>
```

A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable. In the above example, hello, can be used as the name of a variable by using two dollar signs. i.e.

```
<?php $$a = 'world'; ?>
```

echo $man; will not return anything as there is no value set.